# How do I make a layout fixed in mdl as the layout moves on swipe in small screen devices?

Tags: html, css, material-design, progressive-web-apps

I am building a pwa using mdl as front end in firebase. While swiping the app on small screen devices, the layout moves instead of being fixed.

Have attached the pic of the bug.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1B0t8qFu-Cvbg-pgK6ElMjHoNOF-r7ldp/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a tour of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  We cannot help you if you do not provide any code - see how to create a [MCVE]